# WPF - Good Way to take a list to a Tree

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listview, tree

I have a list that looks like this:

```
Base/Level1/Item1
Base/Level1/Item2
Base/Level1/Sub1/Item1
Base/Level2/Item1
Base/Level3/Sub1/Item1
```

I would like an easy way put that into a ListView.  (Ie similar to this)

```
Base
  |
  +->Level1
  |    |
  |    +=Item1
  |    +=Item2
  |    |
  |    +->Sub1
  |        |
  |        +=Item1
  |
  +->Level2
  |    |
  |    +=Item1

  |
  +->Level3
       |
       +->Sub1
           |
           +=Item1
```

Is there an established way to make this kind of conversion or do I just need to roll my own parser?

(In case it may be relevant the real items in my code are TFS Iteration Paths.)

Comment: are you saying that you dont have a hierarchical data structure? just a flat list?

Comment: Well, I am taking it to a list from an XML structure that is beyond my understanding.  So yes I have a flat list.  (Think of it a a list of file paths that I want to show in a TreeView)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will take your list of strings and turn it into a tree suitable for viewing with TreeView as you described:

```
public IList BuildTree(IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
  return
    from s in strings
    let split = s.Split("/")
    group s by s.Split("/")[0] into g  // Group by first component (before /)
    select new
    {
      Name = g.Key,
      Children = BuildTree(            // Recursively build children
        from s in grp
        where s.Length > g.Key.Length+1
        select s.Substring(g.Key.Length+1)) // Select remaining components
    };
}
```

This will return a tree of anonymous types, each containing a Name property and a Children property.  This can be bound directly to the `TreeView` by specifying a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` with `ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"` and content consisting of a `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">` or similar.

Alternatively you could define a tree node class in code if you want additional members or semantics.  For example, given this node class:

```
public class Node 
{
  public string Name { get; set; } 
  public List<Node> Children { get; set; } 
}
```

your BuildTree function would be slightly different:

```
public List<Node> BuildTree(IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
  return (
    from s in strings
    let split = s.Split("/")
    group s by s.Split("/")[0] into g  // Group by first component (before /)
    select new Node
    {
      Value = g.Key,
      Children = BuildTree(            // Recursively build children
        from s in grp
        where s.Length > g.Key.Length+1
        select s.Substring(g.Key.Length+1)) // Select remaining components
    }
    ).ToList();
}
```

Again this can be bound directly using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.  I generally use the first solution (anonymous types) unless I want to do something special with the tree nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The WPF `TreeView` can display hierarchical data using `HierarchicalDataTemplates`. However, currently your data is flat, so you will have to transform it to a hierarchical data structure. There is no built-in way to do that for you...

For instance, you can create a class like that :

```
class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Parse your flat data into a list of `Node` objects with subnodes , and create a `TreeView` with the following `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in the resources :

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfNodes}">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The tree nodes will be automatically generated based on your data. If you need different classes for different levels of the hierarchy, create a different `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for each class

Answer (score 1):

A more generic implementation could be this one. Imagine a `Node` class defined as:

```
public class Node<TItem, TKey>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Data { get; set; }
    public List<Node<TItem, TKey>> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and two generic `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods:

```
public static List<Node<TItem, TKey>> ToTree<TItem, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TItem> list, params Func<TItem, TKey>[] keySelectors)
{
    return list.ToTree(0, keySelectors);
}

public static List<Node<TItem, TKey>> ToTree<TItem, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TItem> list, int nestingLevel, params Func<TItem, TKey>[] keySelectors)
{
    Stack<Func<TItem, TKey>> stackSelectors = new Stack<Func<TItem, TKey>>(keySelectors.Reverse());
    if (stackSelectors.Any())
    {
        return list
            .GroupBy(stackSelectors.Pop())
            .Select(x => new Node<TItem, TKey>()
            {
                Key = x.Key,
                Level = nestingLevel,
                Data = x.ToList(),
                Children = x.ToList().ToTree(nestingLevel + 1, stackSelectors.ToArray())
            })
            .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
```

You can use these methods to aggregate a flat list of user objects to a tree, with an arbitrary aggregation level and a more elegant syntax. The only limitation is that the aggregation keys must be of the same type.

Example:

```
class A
{
    public int a { get;set; }
    public int b { get;set; }
    public int c { get;set; }
    public int d { get;set; }
    public string s { get;set; }

    public A(int _a, int _b, int _c, int _d, string _s)
    {
        a = _a;
        b = _b;
        c = _c;
        d = _d;
        s = _s;     
    }
}

void Main()
{
    A[] ls = {
        new A(0,2,1,10,"one"),
        new A(0,1,1,11,"two"),
        new A(0,0,2,12,"three"),
        new A(0,2,2,13,"four"),
        new A(0,0,3,14,"five"),
        new A(1,0,3,15,"six"),
        new A(1,1,4,16,"se7en"),
        new A(1,0,4,17,"eight"),
        new A(1,1,5,18,"nine"),
        new A(1,2,5,19,"dunno")
    };

    var tree = ls.ToTree(x => x.a, x => x.b, x => x.c, x => x.d);

}
```

Notes: This implementation is not a "real" tree, since there is no single root node, but you can implement a `Tree<TItem, TKey>` wrapper class quite easily.

HTH